# ForEach with @State property

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I have an `@State` property (in the example `@State var parent: Parent`), with an array property which I want to iterate over in a `ForEach` loop in SwiftUI. This works fine when I do

```
ForEach(parent.children, id: \.self) { child in
    ChildView(child: child)
}
```

although I believe that adding a `$` to the call to [correctly pass it to the child view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state). However then I get an error of `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`.

What is the correct way to solve this and why is this code incorrect?

## Minimal code for reproduction

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

func setup() -> Parent {
    let child = Child(name: "foo")
    let parent = Parent(name: "bar")
    parent.children = [child]
    return parent
}

class Parent {
    var name: String
    var children: [Child] = []

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Child: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Child, rhs: Child) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.name)
    }

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let parent = setup()
        let parentView = ParentView(parent: parent)

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: parentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State var child: Child

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child “\(child.name)”")
        }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var parent: Parent

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent “\(parent.name)”")
            // ForEach($parent.children, id: \.self) { child in
            // Yields error:
            // Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
            ForEach(parent.children, id: \.self) { child in
                ChildView(child: child)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let parent = setup()
        return ParentView(parent: parent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the dollar sign would be only if you are trying to pass in Binding<child> or Binding<parent> which to my knowledge you are not. The only time you'd be using _ or $ is with objects that are @propertyWrappers. I don't see why you'd need to here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why You need the dollar sign here but I would change this code following

```
class Parent: ObservableObject {
    var name: String
    @Published
    var children: [Child] = []

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Child: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Child, rhs: Child) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.name)
    }

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State var child: Child

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child “\(child.name)”")
        }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var parent: Parent

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent “\(parent.name)”")
            // ForEach($parent.children, id: \.self) { child in
            // Yields error:
            // Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
            ForEach(parent.children, id: \.self) { child in
                ChildView(child: child)
            }
        }
    }
}
```